# Java splitting map from a nested map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have a nested map as follows,

```
 {domains={A={"name":"R01","uniqueId":"9SJE"},B={"name":"B01","uniqueId":"9BJE"},C={"name":"C01","uniqueId":"9CJE"}}
```

How to split it into an individual map by passing the key and get the value as map.

**Actual MAP** will be as follows:

```
{ domains={img1={"name":"R01","uniqueId":"9SJE"},img2={={"name":"B01","uniqueId":"9BJE"}}}
```

Comment: Is it a jSon or what ?

Comment: Show use the code you have tried so far.

Comment: yes it is a plain map not json

Comment: Why do you think the input has linebreaks? Maybe it is a string that must be parsed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question is unclear so I'll try to answer, but listing my assumptions.
If my assumptions are incorrect, then ofcourse the answer is going to be incorrect.

I am assuming that the {domains={A={  notation does not mean you have this as text but that you have a map containing a map, containing a map.

I am assuming you want to get at the inner map of A, B, C

this would work like this:

```
public Map<String,String> getDomainProperties(Map map, String domainName) {
   if (!map.containsKey("domain") {
      return null; // or throw an exception if you prefer.
   }
   Map domainMap = map.get("domain");
   if (!domainMap.containsKey(domainName)) {
      return null; // or throw IllegalArgumentException or similar if you prefer
   }

   return (Map<String,String>) domainMap.get(domainName);
}
```

you get some warnings about casting because the input map is not specified. From your example it would be something like:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> but that seemed a bit messy to write in the example
```

Comment: -1? leave a comment with an explanation as to why please. I might have made a mistake, but as pseudo code this should be helpful to the OP